# Godotsteam initialization on Linux

Tags: godot, linux, steam, steamworks

I have a problem in getting godotsteam running on my linux OS (Zorin OS).

Here is what I have done so far:

- I have downloaded godosteam addon for using it on godot 4.1.2 from the github official page
- created an account on Steam and logged in Steamworks but not paying the 100$ fee
- downloaded steam and running it on my pc while working on Godot
- created new steam_appid.txt (writing 480 as in documentation)
- wrote these 2 lines inside main script:

  var err = Steam.steamInit()

  print(err)

But, here is the output I get:

```
{ "status": 20, "verbal": "Steam not running." }
```

What could be a possible solution to this problem?